# How to print both the grep pattern and the resulting matched line on the same line?

Tags: bash, awk, while-loop

I have two files File01 and File02.

File01, looks like this:

```
BU24DRAFT_430534
BU24DRAFT_488391
BU24DRAFT_488386
BU24DRAFT_417707
BU24DRAFT_417704
BU24DRAFT_488335
BU24DRAFT_429509
BU24DRAFT_210092
BU24DRAFT_229465
BU24DRAFT_498094
BU24DRAFT_416051
BU24DRAFT_482795
BU24DRAFT_4305
BU24DRAFT_10621
BU24DRAFT_4883
```

File02, looks like this:

```
XP_033390445.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_430534_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79
XP_033390442.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_488391_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79
XP_033390437.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_488386_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79
XP_033390400.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_417707_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79
XP_033390397.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_417704_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79
XP_033390371.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_488335_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79
XP_033376581.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_429509_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79
XP_033376580.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_210092_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79
XP_033376578.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_229465,_partial_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79
XP_033376577.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_498094,_partial_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79
XP_033376576.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_416051,_partial_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79
XP_033376575.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_482795,_partial_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79
```

Using the string from File01, via grep, I would like to identify the lines in File02 that match and with this information generate a file that would look like this:

```
XP_033390442.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_488391_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_488391
XP_033390437.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_488386_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_488386
XP_033390400.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_417707_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_417707
XP_033390397.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_417704_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_417704
XP_033390371.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_488335_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_488335
XP_033376581.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_429509_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_429509
XP_033376580.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_210092_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_210092
XP_033376578.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_229465,_partial_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_229465
XP_033376577.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_498094,_partial_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_498094
XP_033376576.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_416051,_partial_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_416051
XP_033376575.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_482795,_partial_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_482795
```

I tried generating such file using the following code:

```
while read r;do CMD01=$(echo $r);CMD02=$(grep $r File01); echo "$CMD02 $CMD01";done < File02 | awk '(NR>1) && ($2 > 2 ) '
```

The problem I run into is that what I obtain extra matching lines:

```
XP_033390445.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_430534_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_4305
XP_033390371.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_488335_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_4883
```

Where, for example, the string: `BU24DRAFT_4305` is wrongly recognizing the string: `XP_033390445.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_430534_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79`

This result is incorrect. The string in File01 must match a string in File02 that has a complete version of File01's string

Any ideas that could help me will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes that was wrong, I wanted full matches. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the updated sample input and full-matching requirement and assuming you never have any regexp metacharacters in file1 and that the matching strings in file2 are never at the start or end of the line:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{strs[$0]; next} {for (str in strs) if ($0 ~ ("[^[:alnum:]]"str"[^[:alnum:]]")) print $0, str}' file1 file2
XP_033390445.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_430534_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_430534
XP_033390442.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_488391_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_488391
XP_033390437.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_488386_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_488386
XP_033390400.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_417707_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_417707
XP_033390397.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_417704_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_417704
XP_033390371.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_488335_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_488335
XP_033376581.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_429509_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_429509
XP_033376580.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_210092_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_210092
XP_033376578.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_229465,_partial_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_229465
XP_033376577.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_498094,_partial_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_498094
XP_033376576.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_416051,_partial_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_416051
XP_033376575.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_482795,_partial_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_482795
```

---

Original answer doing partial matching:

The correct approach is 1 call to awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{strs[$0]; next} {for (str in strs) if (index($0,str)) print $0, str}' file1 file2
XP_033376575.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_482795,_partial_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_482795
XP_033376576.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_416051,_partial_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_416051
XP_033376577.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_498094,_partial_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_498094
XP_033376578.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_229465,_partial_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_229465
XP_033376580.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_210092_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_210092
XP_033376581.1_uncharacterized_protein_BU24DRAFT_429509_Aaosphaeria_arxii_CBS_175.79 BU24DRAFT_429509
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for some of the issues with the script in your question.

Comment: First. Thanks for your help. Second, your code, which is extremely fast, also has the same problem I observe and explain above in my edited post. Please let me know if this can be solved using your approach.

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea what `there must be a one to one correlation between the gene name and its corresponding processed protein` means. See the comment I added under your question.

Comment: Edited the question. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: OK, I updated my answer based on your new input, output, and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like yours mostly works.  A lot of what you are doing here is unnecessary.  Here is your script broken into multiple lines for readability:

```
while read r; do 
    CMD01=$(echo $r)
    CMD02=$(grep $r zztest01)
    echo "$CMD02 $CMD01"
done < <(head zztest) | awk '(NR>1) && ($2 > 2 ) '
```

First, `CMD01=$(echo $r)`:  This is really the same (or intended to be) as `CMD01="$r"` so kind of useless.

Then, `< <(head zztest)`:  You are using head to output the contents of the file.  This actually works just as well with a simple redirection like this: `< zztest`.

Last, `| awk '(NR>1) && ($2 > 2 ) '`: This appears to just be some sort of logic on whether we are going to print anything or not.

Here is a simplified version:

```
while read r; do
  CMD02=$(grep "$r" zztest01) && echo "$CMD02 $r"
done < zztest
```

**Explanation**

`CMD02=$(grep $r zztest01) && echo "$CMD02 $r"`: The main part of this is really two commands separated by `&&`.  This means execute the second command if the first one succeeded.  `grep` will return a "failure" code if it does not find what it is looking for.  So, if `grep` does not find a match, `echo` will not run.

The output of `grep` will be stored in the variable `$CMD02`.  Then, you will echo that along with `$r` for each match.

If you really want to keep this on one line like the original:

```
while read r; do CMD02=$(grep "$r" zztest01) && echo "$CMD02 $r"; done < zztest
```

**Update**

If you want to avoid partial matches as Ed asked, you can change the grep to this `grep "$r[^0-9]" zztest01`.  This will avoid a match if there is a trailing digit after the initial match string (which is really an assumption given the sample).

Comment: I tested your command on the large genome files and it works!. Thank You!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Upon further QC, I found the output of your code to have the same problem I described on my edited post above.

Answer (score 0):

While not explicit in the question, it seems that each pattern should only match single line in the input file (File02).

Based on this observation, possible to improve performance of the solution from Ed Morton:

```
awk '
NR==FNR{strs[$0]; next}
{ for (str in strs) if (index($0,str)) { print $0, str ; delete strs[str]; next } }
' file1 file2
```

For large files. with many patterns, it will reduce runtime by a factor of 4.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your code is very fast, but again, upon further QC, I found the output of your code to have the same problem I described on my edited post above.